# Scent neutralizer

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I'm an avid outdoorsman and outdoors photographer. I use a lot of scent neutralizers to help me stay hidden. Buying the store brands get expensive so I found a recipe to make your own. the recipe is 1.5 quart 3% hydrogen peroxide, 2 quarts distilled water, .5 cup baking soda, 1 ounce unscented laundry detergent.  The recipe does work  but goes bad fairly quickly, and can't use the brown bottles of hydrogen peroxide, it has additives and stabilizers that have an odor.

Is there anything that I can use as a stabilizer to it have a longer shelf life that doesn't have an odor and safe to the skin? I know the store brands have an additive to give it a longer shelf life but they don't say what they use.

Comment: Keep your 1% peroxide and the rest separated until use.